# How to add a fixed value to a int column in mysql without using SUM

Tags: mysql

I hav a simple query

```
 SELECT id from table1
```

I want to ad 20000 to each id but i don't want to use SUM() (That's because i can't use GROUP BY)

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you're asking to just `SELECT` the data or if you actually want to `UPDATE` the table, so I'll give both.

```
SELECT id + 20000 AS IncrementedId
    FROM table1

UPDATE table1
    SET id = id + 20000
```